# VBA Excel: Error 400 on Cells.Value

Tags: vba, excel

I get a 400 error on Cells.Value in the following function:

```
Function Add_Buttons(myColumn)

    Dim btn As Button
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
    Dim t As Range

    'Search for last row
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Force-Update
    Application.Calculate

    'Generate a button for each cell, if it's not empty
    For i = 3 To lastRow
        Set t = Range(Cells(i, myColumn), Cells(i, myColumn))
        If Cells(i, t.column - 1).Text = "Nicht OK" Then
            Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.RowHeight)
            With btn
              .OnAction = "'DieseArbeitsmappe.Update_DB """ & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, myColumn).Value & """'" 'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
              .Caption = "Update"
              .Name = "Btn_" & ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & i
            End With
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

I can't find any mistakes in my code. It's defintely something with `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, myColumn).Value`, because without this argument, the `.OnAction` works fine.

Comment: It worked for me, other than for myColumn being `1`, as cells(1,0) doesnt exist

Comment: For myColumn I set a letter, in this case "I". Could this be the reason why it fails? In my opinion it shouldn't make a difference if you set a number or a letter.

Comment: Try using `Chr(34)` for your double quotes that you want to be in a string.

Comment: Good idea, but I already tried this without success.

Comment: Update: I recognized, that the strings in my column have apostophes. I guess there is the problem. The apostophes in Cells.Value terminate the string in .OnAction, what causes the 400 error. Is there a way to escape these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. If you have a similar case, make sure your quotes in the cells are already escaped. This way you avoid this error.